# Which hypervisors use full/para virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, hypervisor

So I kind of understand what the difference is between full virtualization and para virtualization.

With full virtualization, the guest OS doesn't know that it is being virtualized. 
With para virtualization, the guest OS needs to know that it is virtualized in order to take advantage of the functions.

I'm comparing four hypervisors: KVM, Red Hat Virtualization 4, vSphere 6.5 and Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V. Now I'm wondering which ones use full virtualization and which ones use para virtualization. As far as I've seen some of them can make use of both but I don't know in which situations which one is used.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Answer (score 5):

Please find the difference in the corresponding post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462581/what-is-the-difference-between-full-para-and-hardware-assisted-virtualiazation

The most of hypervisors can be configured in both ways but one at same time. Therefore, in order to suggest you more convenient options, please describe the project with more specifics.

Comment: I already looked at that post when doing my research, but thanks. Basically I'm just wondering what type of virtualization is the most used for the hypervisors that I listed (KVM, RHV 4.0, vSphere 6.5, Hyper-V 2016).

Comment: It completely depends on project requirements and hardware available for it. From my experience with vSphere 6.5, Hyper-V full virtualization is used more frequently. If you could share us with the project description, we could provide you with recommendations and guidance of what type of virtualization to use and why.

Comment: From my experience, most of Europe is using Hyper-V. Most of USA is using VMware. I would use VMware for larger infrastructure.